# set textview's text using Html.fromHtml inside a loop?

Tags: android, html, textview

Is possible to use Html.fromHtml to the String fetchData, to change some of the text style? This text assigned to a textView outside the loop.
Here is the related code:

```
if( c != null && c.moveToFirst() ){
        while (c.isAfterLast()==false) {
            String gtWord = c.getString(1);
            String gtDef = c.getString(2);
            fetchData = fetchData + getResources().getString(R.string.wordLabel) + gtWord + "\n"
                    + getResources().getString(R.string.transLabel) + gtDef + "\n\n";
            c.moveToNext();
        }
getData.setText(fetchData)
```

Right now I'm using strings.xml in which I've set the text like this:

```
<b>Word: </b>
```

but the style is ignored. I'found some related questions and I've tried to do it without using strings.xml also, but the only tag recognized is the 
, all others ignored. I'm supposing that the problem is that I'm using mixed variables and hardcoded text inside loop, because I tested it outside the loop like this:

```
getData.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>This<b/> is <u>underlined<u/> text")
```

and it's working.

Answer (score 1):

Declaire your string like this

```
<string name="wordLabel"><![CDATA[<b>Word: </b>]]></string>
```

---

From [documentaion](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StylingWithHTML) you can also write it as

```
<string name="word_label">&lt;b>Word: &lt;/b></string> // here I have chnaged your string name wordLabel to word_label. you should follow naming convension.
```

*Notice that the opening bracket is HTML-escaped, using the `&lt;` notation.*

Comment: Doesn't work. The text appears like this <b>Word: </b>

Comment: No difference, same result again.

Comment: Print the final value of fetchData string and share what you are getting. So it will be easy to find root cause :)

Comment: No difference if I use "&gt;" instead of "<" also

Comment: I am asking about share the string value.

Comment: Print string fetchData before `getData.setText(fetchData)`. So we can see what string you are getting.

Comment: I desided to use webview instead. Works fine and after first load displays the text faster than the textview. Thanks for your help anyway.